# How to auto-scale JavaFX LineChart if an invisible series present?

Tags: javafx, linechart

I need a possibility of show/hide the series on my LineChart. For now I'm doing that like this:

```
series.getNode().setVisible(false);
```

But though the series is invisible after this, a chart axis autorange still takes into account an range of the series data. I tired set up managed property also:

```
series.getNode().setVisible(false);
series.getNode().setManaged(false);
```

but without success. So, is there a some way to hide a series and exclude it from the axis autorange?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, the only way to do so for now is to extend `LineChart` and override `updateAxisRange()` to modify it to consider only visible series:

```
public class MLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart<X, Y> {

  public MLineChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis) {
    super(xAxis, yAxis);
  }

  @Override
  protected void updateAxisRange() {
    final Axis<X> xa = getXAxis();
    final Axis<Y> ya = getYAxis();
    List<X> xData = null;
    List<Y> yData = null;
    if (xa.isAutoRanging()) xData = new ArrayList<X>();
    if (ya.isAutoRanging()) yData = new ArrayList<Y>();
    if (xData != null || yData != null) {
      for (Series<X, Y> series : getData()) {
        if (series.getNode().isVisible()) { // consider only visible series
          for (Data<X, Y> data : series.getData()) {
            if (xData != null) xData.add(data.getXValue());
            if (yData != null) yData.add(data.getYValue());
          }
        }
      }
      // RT-32838 No need to invalidate range if there is one data item - whose value is zero.
      if (xData != null && !(xData.size() == 1 && getXAxis().toNumericValue(xData.get(0)) == 0)) {
        xa.invalidateRange(xData);
      }
      if (yData != null && !(yData.size() == 1 && getYAxis().toNumericValue(yData.get(0)) == 0)) {
        ya.invalidateRange(yData);
      }

    }
  }
}
```